# JAVA_HOME get unset on Windows 8

Tags: java, windows-8, jruby

I'm working on Windows 8 using oracle Java 7 and JRuby (from TorqueBox 2.2.0).
In the terminal the JAVA_HOME environment variable has some weird behaviors ...

If I enter "set" I get what I'm expecting:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
```

I can for instance run bundle exec rspec and it will work
Then I run

```
set COVERAGE=true
```

and run the same command again and I will get

```
Cannot locate Java installation, specified by JAVA_HOME:
```

I can enter this several time, always the same result. But mysteriously I can sometime do something like

```
jruby -S bundle exec spec
```

and it will sometimes work ... sometimes not ...

It's totally random and unpredictable ... it's a real pain !
Anyone any idea ? From my point of view it just looks like an old Windows bug because everything was fine on Windows 7

Already tested:

- installing the x64 Java instead of the x86
- have a trailing / at the end of the path

Comment: What happens if you change JAVA_HOME to point to the JDK (where javac.exe resides) rather than the JRE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may have to do with the whitespace inside of the path. You've defined it properly, but some scripts may use it like this:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java ...
```

which will fail. In cases like this, one always must remember the quote marks:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" ...
```

Except that you say the behaviour is random... Anyway, try moving the installation to a folder without whitespace in the name, see what it does.

Comment: I'm not sure if it was exactly this ... I moved the Java installation folder to a no-space path and had a new error showing up
Cannot locate Java installation, specified by JAVA_HOME: ...my_path...\jre
It was searching the jre inside my jre. So I pointed JAVA_HOME to my Java JDK instead of the JRE and don't have any issue since.